# Cannot build gst-template project

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am working on developing my first gstreamer plugin. Per the documentation at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/boiler.html?gi-language=c, they direct you to download the gst-template project at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template.git. The project's README.md says the first step in building the project is to run

```
meson build
```

However, when I do, I get the error:

```
Run-time dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gstreamer-1.0

meson.build:11:0: ERROR: Neither a subproject directory nor a gstreamer.wrap file was found.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am building on Windows 10.
Thanks, David